# Graph cut using Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, image-segmentation

I am trying to apply graph cut method for my segmentation task. I found some example codes at
[Graph_Cut_Demo](http://read.pudn.com/downloads151/sourcecode/math/653078/Graph%20Cut/graphcuts_demo.m__.htm).

Part of the codes are showing below

```
img = im2double( imread([ImageDir 'cat.jpg']) ); 
[ny,nx,nc] = size(img); 
d = reshape( img, ny*nx, nc );  
k = 2; % number of clusters 
[l0 c] = kmeans( d, k ); 
l0 = reshape( l0, ny, nx ); 

% For each class, the data term Dc measures the distance of 
% each pixel value to the class prototype. For simplicity, standard 
% Euclidean distance is used. Mahalanobis distance (weighted by class 
% covariances) might improve the results in some cases.  Note that the 
% image intensity values are in the [0,1] interval, which provides 
% normalization.   

Dc = zeros( ny, nx, k ); 
for i = 1:k 
  dif = d - repmat( c(i,:), ny*nx,1 ); 
  Dc(:,:,i) = reshape( sum(dif.^2,2), ny, nx ); 
end
```

It seems that the method used k-means clustering to initialise the graph and get the data term Dc. However, I don't understand how they calculate this data term. Why they use

```
dif = d - repmat( c(i,:), ny*nx,1 );
```

In the comments thy said the data term `Dc` measures the distance of each pixel value to the class prototype. What is the class prototype, and why it can be determined by k-means label?

In another implementation [Graph_Cut_Demo2](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~bagon/matlab_code/example.zip), it used

```
% calculate the data cost per cluster center
Dc = zeros([sz(1:2) k],'single');
for ci=1:k
    % use covariance matrix per cluster
    icv = inv(cov(d(l0==ci,:)));    
    dif = d- repmat(c(ci,:), [size(d,1) 1]);
    % data cost is minus log likelihood of the pixel to belong to each
    % cluster according to its RGB value
    Dc(:,:,ci) = reshape(sum((dif*icv).*dif./2,2),sz(1:2));
end
```

This confused me a lot. Why they calculate the covariance matrix and how they formed the data term using minus log likelihood? Any papers or descriptions available for these implementation?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Both graph-cut segmentation examples are strongly related. The authors of [*Image Processing, Analysis, and Machine Vision: A MATLAB Companion*](http://visionbook.felk.cvut.cz/) book (first example) used the graph cut wrapper code of [Shai Bagon](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~bagon/matlab.html#graphcut) (with the author's permission naturally) - the second example.

So, what is the data term anyway?
The data term represent how each pixel *independently* is likely to belong to each label. This is why log-likelihood terms are used.

More concretely, in these examples you try to segment the image into `k` segments based on their colors. 
You assume there are only `k` dominant colors in the image (not a very practical assumption, but sufficient for educational purposes).
Using `k`-means you try and find what are these two colors. The output of `k`-means is `k` centers in RGB space - that is `k` "representative" colors. 
The likelihood of each pixel to belong to any of the `k` centers is inversely proportional to the distance (in color space) of the pixel from the representative `k`-th center: the larger the distance the less likely the pixel to belong to the `k`-th center, the higher the unary energy penalty one must "pay" to assign this pixel to the `k`-th cluster.
The second example takes this notion one step ahead and assumes that the `k` clusters may have different densities in color space, modeling this second order behavior using a covariance matrix for each cluster.

In practice, one uses a more sophisticated color model for each segment, usually a mixture of Gaussians. You can read about it in the seminal paper of [GrabCut](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~vision/courses/2006_2/papers/vid_seg/grabcut_siggraph04.pdf) (section 3).

PS,
Next time you can email Shai Bagon directly and ask.